# use array methods to set changeable header for table in es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want make a table with headers from 8 to 23 and use es6 and arrays methods I have this code to make array:

```
const column = Array.from(Array(16), (_, x) => [x + 8]).fill({
    title: 8,
});
```

My current output :
[image]

Expected output :

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index provided by the callback to increment from 8 forward

```js
const column = Array.from({ length: 16 }, (_, i) => ({ title: 8 + i }));

console.log(column)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const column = Array.from(Array(16), (_, x) => [x + 8]).map(e => {
  return { title: e[0] }
});
```